# Передача значения input в checkbox, а оттуда в sql

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, sql

Всем привет. Помогите пожалуйста, хочу сделать так, чтобы пользователь выбирая товар на сайте просто ставил галку в чекбоксе и рядом вписывал в инпут количество этого товара и в конце концов, когда всё выберет и выставит количество, отправлял в таблицу, но у меня не очень получается помогите пожалуйста.

Сначала я хотел просто в value чекбокса прописать через php переменную со значением input, но как то не получилось, как не пытался. Теперь я пробую через форму, но всё равно не понимаю, что делаю не так. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Вот форма:

```
 <form action="get_value.php" method="get" name="order">

        <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input  type="checkbox" class="form">
              </span>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount1">
            </div><!-- /input-group -->

            </form>
```

Вот get_value.php:

```
<?php

$b = $_GET['amount1'];
echo $b;


?>
```

Вот запрос в sql:

```
$success = $mysqli-> query ("INSERT INTO `orders`.`orders` (`ID`, `Name`, `Email`, `Adress`, `ContactNum`, `Order`, `Payment`, `Time`) VALUES (NULL, '".$name."', '".$email."', '".$adress."', '".$contact."', '".$order."', '".$optionSep."', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");
```

Comment: а где `<input type="submit"/>`?

Comment: Если его добавляю то редиректит на другую страницу(при нажатии естесно). Как сделать правильно, чтобы уже наконец достичь желаемого?

Comment: в js добавь `event.preventDefault();` тогда не будет редиректа

Answer (score 0):

Данные из формы можно получить или при нажатии на кнопку submit или же  передавать данные при помощи ajax.
Редирект по нажатию на submit у Вас происходит т.к. указан action в форме, куда и происходит редирект.
Самы простой способ - заменить кнопку submit на просто кнопку и по нажатию на нее обращатся к JS функции которая уже будет передавать Ваши данные в скрипт записи в бд.

```
<input type='button' onclick='saveToDb()' value='Status Update'>
```

Сама функция будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
function saveToDb()
{

    $(function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'get_value.php, 
            data: "", // данные из input и checkbox
            dataType: 'json'
        });

    });
}
```